# Host React app and Wordpress in one domain

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, web, hosting, web-hosting

**Respected Developers**
I have an issue in web hosting. First of all, I would like to sorry you in advance as you may not be able to understand well because of my inexperienced English.

I have already prepared built react app and landing page of WordPress.
What I want to do is when I type in the browser just like https://myapp.com, it goes to my WordPress landing page, then that landing page will have some links to the react app.
So, WordPress page is only for the first encounter of my site, and all the contents will be shown by react.
Godaddy domain name has already been bought.
All left is to host 2 different apps to one domain. How can I do it without fail?
Could you please tell me how to do it? I will be happy if someone helps me with the good opinion.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have not get the clear answer yet. But I just wonder if I should use the Nginx for the react app hosting. Or is this kind of hosing impossible???